# MVC4 View decision based on number of items in Select List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am creating an MVC4 application using the Razor View engine and I would like to make a decision in my `View` based on the number of items in a `Select List`. My Select Lists are created in the controller and saved in the ViewData collection. Basically, if there is only one item available in the select list, I plan to hide the dropdown in the view and hard-code the value using a hidden field.

When I access the "Items" property, Intellisense does not provide a method to count the number of List Items. How do I count the items in the select list from the Razor View?

Index.cshtml

```
@model Mvc4.Models.PhoneRecord
...
    <div class="editor-field">
        @{
            // I need logic here to count items in the select list.
            // XXXXX is of course a compile error, there is no Intellisense
            // option that provides a "count" method, what should I use?
            if (((SelectList)ViewData["_CellPhoneCarrier"]).Items.XXXXX == 1)) 
            {
                @Html.Raw("note: value is hardcoded.")
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CellPhoneCarrier)
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CellPhoneCarrier, (SelectList)ViewData["_CellPhoneCarrier"])
            }
        }
    </div>
...
```

Comment: Why not to put information into strongly typed model - would be so much easier to use?..

Comment: You *should* be able to use Count() (linq extension) I believe, intellisense or not. On another note, Alexei's suggestion is even better!

Comment: Alexei, I used ViewData because that is how the tutorial showed - I don't like it tbh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you just need to make use of the `Count()` method, like so:

```
if (((SelectList)ViewData["_CellPhoneCarrier"]).Items.Count() == 1))
```

However, I agree with Alexei.  Creating views is much easier when you make use of strongly-typed models.  You could have something like this:

```
public class CellPhoneCarriersViewModel
{
    public SelectList Items { get; set; }
    public int CellPhoneCarrier { get; set; }
}
```

Now, instead of storing your `SelectList` inside `ViewData`, you can create it in your controller and have direct access to it:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new CellPhoneCarriersViewModel();
    model.Items = new SelectList(...);

    return View(model);
}
```

There's no longer a need to mess around casting things inside the view.  So the view becomes:

```
@if (Model.Items.Count() == 1)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CellPhoneCarrier)
}
else
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CellPhoneCarrier, Model.Items)
}
```

If you're going to use this in several places, you could clean your views up even further by writing an extension method to do this for you:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static HtmlString HiddenOrDropDownFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> target, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList)
    {
        if (selectList.Count() == 1)
            return helper.HiddenFor(target);

        return helper.DropDownListFor(target, selectList);
    }
}
```

Then use it in your view like so:

```
@Html.HiddenOrDropDownFor(m => m.CellPhoneCarrier, Model.Items)
```

Comment: I tried `Items.Count()` first, it throws a compile error for me: `System.Collections.IEnumerable does not contain a definition for Count ...`

Comment: @LaylaRenee The `.Count()` method is a LINQ extension method.  You need to add a `using System.Linq;` statement.

Comment: This worked great. I added the Select List property to my ViewModel and used it as explained here. Using the strongly-typed approach is far superior to what I was using, thanks much. I also really appreciate that "bonus answer" regarding the HtmlExtensions!

Comment: That still didn't quite work for me, but changing it by removing `.Items` to `if (((SelectList)ViewData["_CellPhoneCarrier"]).Count() == 1)` worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the SelectionList in the Model. Then in your View you could do something like this:

```
      @{
        int nbrOfCarrier = Model.CellPhoneCarrierList().Count();

        if (nbrOfCarrier > 1)
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CellPhoneCarrier,Model.CellPhoneCarrierList())   
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CellPhoneCarrier, "1")
        }

    }
```

and in the Model,

```
   public List<SelectListItem> CellPhoneCarrierList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> x = new List<SelectListItem>();
        x.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "AT&T", Value = "1" });
        x.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "T-Mobile", Value = "2"});
        x.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Verizon", Value = "3" });
        return x;
    }
```

use Entity Framework and Stored Procedures to populate the Select List. Even add other layers for DAL and BLL for scalability. I would never put code in the controller other than if statements and decisions to process with different methods in the Model based on user input

Comment: I am using a repository layer to populate the items in the select list. How would I incorporate the repository into this method? It seems I would have to either hardcode the repository into the Model or pass the Interface into the method from the view?

Comment: I attempted to test this today, the overload you provided results in a compile error.

Comment: Did you remember to add using System.Web.Mvc in the Model? SelectListItem is under System.Web.Mvc. I tested that code before posting. If you use additional layer, create a class and a method that reads from EF and either return a generic collection or do a foreach in that method and populate List<SelectListItem> and return it. There are many ways to skin a cat. Just be sure to use Web.Mvc

Answer (score 0):

Create an ICollection of CellPhoneCarriers in a viewmodel then use that viewmodel in this view.

aka:

```
public class PhoneRecordVM
{
    public ICollection<CellPhoneCarrier> CellPhoneCarriers { get; set; }

    public PhoneRecordVM(Customer customer)
    {
        CellPhoneCarriers = (db.CellPhoneCarrier)
            .Where(e => e.CarrierZone == customer.Zone)
            .OrderBy(e => e.CellPhoneCarrier.Text))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

In View:

```
if(SelectList(Model.CellPhoneCarriers, "ID", "CellPhoneCarrier.Text", Model.SelectedCellPhoneCarrierID).Count ==1)
{...}
else
{...}
```